# Как в JBoss AS увеличить heap space?

Tags: jboss, spring, утечка-памяти, java-ee, memory

После нескольких часов работы наблюдаю в логах вот такой message:

```
2012-12-28 09:01:33,732 ERROR [STDERR] 2012-12-28 09:01:33,728 [ERROR] org.springframework.integration.message.MessageHandlingException: method 'public void my_package.MyClass.myMethod(java.io.File)' threw an Exception.
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageMappingMethodInvoker.invokeMethod(MessageMappingMethodInvoker.java:113)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:49)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:91)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:59)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:103)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:90)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:43)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:94)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessageChannelTemplate.doSend(MessageChannelTemplate.java:224)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessageChannelTemplate.send(MessageChannelTemplate.java:181)
        at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:59)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:103)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:90)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:43)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:94)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessageChannelTemplate.doSend(MessageChannelTemplate.java:224)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessageChannelTemplate.send(MessageChannelTemplate.java:181)
        at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:59)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:103)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:90)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:43)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:94)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessageChannelTemplate.doSend(MessageChannelTemplate.java:224)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessageChannelTemplate.send(MessageChannelTemplate.java:181)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.doPoll(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:78)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.innerPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:232)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.poll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:216)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:209)
        at org.springframework.integration.scheduling.SimpleTaskScheduler$ErrorHandlingRunnableWrapper.run(SimpleTaskScheduler.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
        at org.springframework.integration.scheduling.SimpleTaskScheduler$TriggeredTask.run(SimpleTaskScheduler.java:256)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler.handleMessageInternal(LoggingHandler.java:83)
```

Вопрос, как увеличить heap space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы понять какую из опций нужно "подкрутить" я рекомендую хорошую статью на Хабре: [Какие бывают типы OutOfMemoryError или из каких частей состоит память java процесса](http://habrahabr.ru/post/117274/)

Т.о. для устранения `Java heap space` нужно тюнить `-Xms` и `-Xmx`

Далее рождается следующий вопрос: как это сделать в `JBoss`? Зависит от того как вы его запускаете. Например, если скриптом, например, так:

```
/opt/jboss-as/bin/standalone.sh
```

То варианта (как минимум) два:

- указать необходимые опции в командной строке: `JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx512m' /opt/jboss-as/bin/standalone.sh`
- установить `JAVA_OPTS` в конфигурационном файле (`/opt/jboss-as/bin/standalone.conf` в моём случае)

P.S. А `Spring` тут не причем.